# Нужна помощь с Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

По непонятной причине не работают ссылки на странице http://foto-uvarovo.ru/portfolio/. Так как абсолютно не шарю в Ajax, возникла проблема. Подскажите хотя бы в каком направлении копать. Любую доп.информацию предоставлю

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: switchAlbum is not defined

Comment: Всё дело в функции SwitchAlbum, у вас её нет, но она подключается

Comment: Видимо какой-то косяк при переносе шаблона случился, что-то потерял) Спасибо за наводку, поищу эту функцию в оригинале